# How to Identify Missing Indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I have a text file with millions of index points that are all interpreted as strings and is tab delimited. However, some index points could be missing. Here is an example of my text file:

```
1       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273   
2       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273   
3       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273   
5       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273   
7       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273   
9       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273
```

Notice that rows 4, 6 and 8 are missing. My goal is to create a function that can parse through the text file, identify possible missing index points and return a list that has all the missing index points (if any) or return nothing.

I'm using Python 3.7 in Spyder IDE Windows10 os. I am relatively new to Python and Stackoverflow.

This is what I've got so far. This works to ID 1 missing index but fails if there are several missing index points.

The error starts after the first else line. I'm not sure how to track the observed index in the doc (1, 2, 3, 5...) with the for loop's index (0, 1, 2, 3...) as missing index points compound over time.

Note, the first 4 rows of the text doc contain header info which I ignore during the parsing that's why data = f.readlines()[4:]

```
  def check_sorted_file(fileName):
        missing_idx = []
        count = 1
            with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
                data = f.readlines()[4:]
                for x, line in enumerate(data):
                    idx = int(line.split()[0])
                    if idx == (count + x): 
                        pass
                    else: 
                        missing_idx.append(count + x)
                        count += 1
                if missing_idx != []:
                    print('\nThe following idicie(s) are missing: ')
                    print(*missing_idx, sep=", ")
                else:   
                    print('\nAll indices are accounted for. ')
                return missing_idx
```

...

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Are you okay with using libraries or do you require / prefer pure Python?

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer pure Python. But if there is a more elegant solution using a library I am OK with that too. @ClarenceLeung

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer give you much better overall solutions, however I want to just help guide your given one in the right direction so you see how you could change yours to work:

```
def check_sorted_file(fileName):
    missing_idx = []
    last_index = 0
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines()[4:]

    for line in data:
        idx = int(line.split()[0])
        if idx == last_index+1:
            pass
        else:
            missing_idx.extend(list(range(last_index+1, idx)))
        last_index = idx

    if missing_idx:
        print('\nThe following idicie(s) are missing: ')
        print(*missing_idx, sep=", ")
    else:
        print('\nAll indices are accounted for. ')
    return missing_idx
```

So instead of needing to use enumerate we will use the incoming index as our guide of where we are at.

To solve multiple missing, we use `range` to get all the numbers between the last index and the current one, and extend our list with that new set of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Python alone:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    indices = [int(row.split('\t')[0]) for row in f.read().split('\n')[4:]]

missing_indices = [index 
                   for index in range(1, len(indices) + 1)
                   if index not in indices]
```

This converts your data into a nested `list` where each outer `list` contains a row and each inner `list` contains an element. Since we only care about the indices, we get the first element and ignore the others.

Then, since the indices are in running order starting from 1, we construct a `range` spanning the *expected* range of indices, and get the indices that exist in that range but not in the file.

Assuming the indices are unique (which seems reasonable), we can also use *DYZ*'s suggestion to use `sets`:

```
missing_indices = set(range(1, len(indices) + 1) - set(indices)
```

`pandas` works fine too:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t').iloc[4:]

range_index = pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df) + 1)
print(range_index[~range_index.isin(df.iloc[:, 0])]
```

This creates a `pandas` DataFrame from your data, cutting off the first four rows. Following the same principle as the other answer, it creates an index with all expected values and takes the subset of it that does not exist in the first column of the DataFrame.

Comment: your code did not work. missing_indices becomes a list counting up. Looks like it counts the number of lines? But not sure i.e [1, 2, 3, 4, 5... end]

Comment: @Tim51 Newbie mistake; I forgot to convert the indices to `int`. Try again; I have edited the code.

Comment: no luck. here is what error code I'm seeing:                                                     indices = [int(row.split('\t')[0]) for row in f.read().split('\n')[4:]]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @Tim51 I cannot reproduce the error on your sample data, after converting the spaces to tabs. Are you sure the elements are tab-separated?

Comment: I'm 99% percent sure its tab delimited. Is there an effective way I can verify?

Comment: so this is the first line that appears in my text file  " "Today's Date...0.00000\t\r\n" ". When you start your list comprehension with int(row.split('t')[0]) it tries to convert that line into an int() and then returns " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @Tim51 It skips the first four rows, so that shouldn't be a problem. Anyway, I see that another answer has worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a large number of rows, you might want to do this in a lazy fashion without making large lists or using `in` to test if every value is in a million line list. You can mix a few of the itertools to do this as an iterator and save the list for the end (if you even need it then).

Basically you make `tee` a `map` into two iterators to get the indexes, knock off a value of one of them with `next()` then zip them checking the difference as you go:

```
from itertools import chain, tee
lines = ["1       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273",
"2       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273",
"3       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273",
"5       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273",
"7       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273",
"9       0       4         0d 07:00:37.0400009155273"
]

#two iterators going over indexes 
i1, i2 = tee(map(lambda x: int(x.split()[0]), lines), 2)

# move one forward
next(i2) 

# chain.from_iterable will be an iterator producing missing indexes: 
list(chain.from_iterable(range(i+1, j) for i, j in zip(i1, i2) if j-i!=1))
```

Result:

```
[4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compact, robust, set-based, core Python-only solution. Read the file, split each line into fields, convert the first field into an int, and build a set of actual indexes:

```
skip = 4 # Skip that many lines
with open(yourfile) as f:
    for _ in range(skip):
        next(f)
    actual = {int(line.split()[0]) for line in f}
```

Create a set of expected indexes and take set difference:

```
expected = set(range(min(actual), max(actual) + 1))
sorted(expected - actual)
#[4, 6, 8]
```

The solution works even when the indexes do not start at 1.

Comment: Yes. It looks at the set of all indexes from the smallest present to the largest present.

Comment: A small issue is that the first 4 lines of my text file contain header information. So the index checker needs to start after line 4. @DYZ

Comment: So, just skip the first four rows.

Comment: Newb question - How can I start after the first 4 lines using your approach? I tried "
    actual = {int(line.split()[0]) for line[4:] in f} and 
    actual = {int(line.split()[0]) for line in f[4:]} I'm not sure how to articulate the syntax here. @DYZ